# ¿Por qué éste código no imprime el número menor del vector?

Tags: c

```
int menorvec (int x[],int n,int menor);
#include<stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int *arreglo,menor,n;
int tamano=0;
int resultado=0;

int main(){

    printf("Ingrese el tamano del arreglo: ");
    scanf("%i",&tamano);
    arreglo = new int[tamano];

    for(int i=0;i<tamano;i++){
      printf("Ingrese el elemento numero %i :",i+1);
      scanf("%i",&arreglo[i]);
    }
    resultado = menorvec(arreglo,tamano,menor);
    printf("El elemento menor de este vector es %d", resultado);
    return 0;
}

int menorvec (int x [], int n, int menor) {
    if (n == 0) {
        if (menor > x [n]) {
           return x [0];
        } else {
           return menor;
        }
    } else {
        if (menor > x [n]) {
           return menorvec (x, n - 1, x [n]);
        } else {
           return menorvec (x, n - 1, menor);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pero ¿esto es [tag:c] o es [tag:c++]?

Answer (score 2):

Estas combinando C++ con C, eso no es correcto. Por otro es considerado como buena práctica de programación que las importaciones deben ir antes de cualquier declaración en la mayoria de casos.

Yendo al problema, el error es causado por que el valor menor no tiene un valor inicial asi que tomara cualquier valor y si es un numero menor que el que esta en *arreglo* será la respuesta incorrecta, asi que se debe inicializar *menor* con algun valor del arreglo, en este caso usare el valor `x[0]`, por otro lado no existe arreglo de 0 asi que el caso `n==0` no tiene sentido. Además el último de un arreglo no es `x[n]` sino `x[n-1]`. Corrigiendo esos errores obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int menorvec (int x[],int n,int menor);

int main(){

    int *arreglo = NULL;
    int menor;
    int tamano=0;
    int resultado=0;

    printf("Ingrese el tamano del arreglo: ");
    scanf("%i",&tamano);
    arreglo = malloc(tamano * sizeof *arreglo);

    for(int i=0;i<tamano;i++){
        printf("Ingrese el elemento numero %i :",i+1);
        scanf("%i",&arreglo[i]);
    }
    menor = arreglo[0];
    resultado = menorvec(arreglo,tamano, menor);
    printf("El elemento menor de este vector es %d", resultado);
    free(arreglo);
    return 0;
}

int menorvec (int x [], int n, int menor) {
    if (n == 1)
        return menor > x[0] ? x[0] : menor;
    else
        return menorvec (x, n - 1, menor > x[n-1] ? x[n-1] : menor);
}
```

Nota: evita las variables globales.

Comment: @eferion lo que señalo es la buena práctica, se que puede ir dentro de una función pero no se debe hacer ello.

Comment: pienso que ambas expresiones son válidas, depende de la perspectiva para mi lo correcto son las buenas prácticas, para ti lo correcto es lo exacto. mi idea es señalar que en este caso en particular no es correcto hacerlo que para este contexto equivale a que no es una buena práctica.

Comment: @eferion que deberia decir: *las importaciones **deben** ir antes de cualquier declaración* o * las importaciones **pueden** ir antes de cualquier declaración*, por otro lado voy a señalar mejor que es una mala práctica para ser más preciso.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82818/discussion-between-eferion-and-eyllanesc).